# Select each company's lowest price for product with specific criteria

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: companies, products, companies_to_products.

companies: **id**, **name**

```
---------------------
|   id   |   name   |
|--------------------
|    1   | Company 1|
|    2   | Company 2|
|    3   | Company 3|
|-------------------|
```

products: **id**, **brand**, **model**

```
----------------------------------
|   id   |   brand   |   model   |
|---------------------------------
|    1   | Brand 1   | Horizontal|
|    2   | Brand 1   |  Vertical |
|    3   | Brand 2   | Horizontal|
|    4   | Brand 2   |  Vertical |
|    5   | Brand 3   | Horizontal|
|    6   | Brand 3   |  Vertical |
|--------------------------------|
```

companies_to_products: **company_id**, **product_id**, **price**

```
-----------------------------------------------
|   company_id   |   product_id   |   price   |
|----------------------------------------------
|        1       |        5       |   19.00   |
|        1       |        2       |   24.00   |
|        1       |        1       |   18.00   |
|        2       |        3       |   21.00   |
|        2       |        2       |   22.00   |
|        3       |        1       |   17.00   |
|        3       |        4       |   20.00   |
|        3       |        6       |   23.00   |
|---------------------------------------------|
```

Each company sells products of the same model, which is my search criteria, though (sometimes) different brands at different prices; sometimes the same brand, though at a different price.

Up to now I've only been interested in selecting a list of the three best-priced products based on a given model, regardless of the company; so, theoretically, one company could take up all three top spots if their prices are all better than the competitions'.

i.e.

```
SELECT ctop.price, c.\*, p.\* 
FROM companies_to_products ctop 
LEFT JOIN products p 
ON p.id = ctop.product_id 
LEFT JOIN companies c 
ON c.id = ctop.company_id 
WHERE p.model = "Vertical" 
ORDER BY ctop.price ASC LIMIT 3
```

would return

```
-----------------------------------------------
|   company_id   |   product_id   |   price   |
|----------------------------------------------
|        2       |        2       |   22.00   |
|        3       |        4       |   20.00   |
|        3       |        6       |   23.00   |
|---------------------------------------------|
```

The problem is, now the specifications have changed; rather than simply showing the three lowest prices, I now need to show each company's lowest prices.

i.e.

```
-----------------------------------------------
|   company_id   |   product_id   |   price   |
|----------------------------------------------
|        1       |        2       |   24.00   |
|        2       |        2       |   22.00   |
|        3       |        4       |   20.00   |
|---------------------------------------------|
```

In this second result set, the third *Vertical* product is no longer Company 3's, but rather Company 1's, so that each of the three companies shows up once in the result set.

I'm having difficulty formulating a single SQL query that could handle this. I'd rather avoid simply selecting each company, and then running each of those through a PHP foreach to get what I'm after. I've attempted a GROUP BY **company_id**, but without luck, the results in the rest of the row being arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

Works only on **`MYSQL`**

```
select comp.id `Company_Id`, prod.id `Product_Id`, MIN(cop.price)
from companies comp
inner join companies_to_products cop on comp.id=cop.company_id
inner join products prod on cop.product_id=prod.id 
where prod.model='Vertical'
group by `Company_Id`
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/04c36/3)**

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried min()? I've just tried it with your data and it works.

```
select company_id,product_id,min(price)
from ctop left join products on products.product_id=ctop.product_id
where model="Vertical"
group by company_id;
```

Comment: This approach does get the correct price, that's to say the minimum price each company can offer; however, the product information returned by this query is arbitrary. When I apply this to my production DB, I get the correct prices, but the wrong product brand.